# Is my proof by contradiction incorrect?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

This problem is Exercise 15 of Chapter 6 of *Book of Proof* by Richard Hammack.

I proved this exercise in a way that was not described in the textbook.

Proposition. If $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \nmid k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $b = 0$.

Proof. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b \nmid k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b \not = 0$. By the definition of divisibility, $k \not = bn$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Hence, $\frac{k}{n} \not = b$. Because $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $ b \not \in \mathbb{Q}$. As $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, $b \not \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, we previously stated that $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is a contradiction that $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \not \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I am aware of an easier method, but I am simply wondering if the method I have described is valid.

Comment: Easier is to consider $b\mid |b|$ for every non-zero integer $b$

Comment: @Peter We have $b \mid |b|$ for _all_ integers $b$, though. No need to exclude $0$.

Comment: @Arthur You are right , for the given exercise we can make this restriction. If $b=0$ , then the only possibility would be $k=0$ which I think is not considered to be a natural number here,

Comment: Do you have doubts or why didn't you ask whether the proof is **correct**?

Comment: @Paul Frost I have doubts about the validity of my method. I apologise for the way I formatted the question.

Comment: The big concern here is your reliance on $\Bbb Q$ and its properties. Mathematics has an "order" in which things need to be developed to avoid circular reasoning. One develops $\Bbb N$ first, then extends to $\Bbb Z$, then to $\Bbb Q$, and so on. This result involves only $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$, so presumably should be provable just from the definitions/axioms of those two sets. But by bringing in $\Bbb Q$, you run the risk of using properties that are proven for $\Bbb Q$ from this result. If it can be proven without knowing about rationals, that is superior.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you! I appreciate this, see my error, and am glad for the insight. Invaluable for a self-studier like myself. :)